# C/C++ GetAsyncKeyState() Key combination

Tags: c++, windows, api

I understand how to use this function with one key, but how can I use it with two keypresses?

Like: GetAsyncKeyStat(VK_LBUTTON && VK_RBUTTON);

Comment: Cargo-cultical questions. Or perhaps experimental programming? Arranging tokens with no understanding what they really mean.

Comment: You should be very careful to check that you really need GetAsyncKeyState - If you don't completely understand the difference between GetKeyState and GetAsyncKeyState, I recommend you use GetKeyState because you probably don't need GetAsyncKeyState - it doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 6):

You would have to call `GetAsyncKeyState` twice.

```
//"And" the returns of GetAsyncKeyState
//Then "and" the result with 0x8000 to get whether or not the Most Significant Bit is set
bool bBothPressed = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) & GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RBUTTON) & 0x8000;
```

Comment: How does & 0x8 test for the most significant bit? I thought 0xF000 would be required?

Comment: Yes, my bad, it was meant to be 0x8000.

Answer (score 2):

Generally the best answer if you want to query multiple keys is to use GetKeyboardState that returns the state of every Virtual key in an array which you can process directly and efficiently.